# What does CI-V stand for?

Tags: jargon, ci-v

In the context of controlling a radio from a computer, what does CI-V stand for? I've noticed in relationship to a jack as well as USB.

For example, from the Icom IC-7300 manual:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> CI-V stands for **C**omputer **I**nterface 5 [Roman numeral "**V**"]
>   and is ICOM's designation for their rig interface to a computer or to
>   another rig. You can find it on most HF and some VHF rigs since the
>   1980s and is has not changed in it's basic structure up to now. CI-V
>   is a simple to use interface which allows --in contrast to other
>   manufacturers' designs-- a "daisy chaining" of rigs.
>
> To connect *just two rigs* you need nothing more than a cable with two
>   3.5mm mini plugs. ***For a connection to a computer***, you need an additional interface for most rigs.

Above quoted from http://www.plicht.de/ekki/civ/civ-p0.html.

The Icom CI-V interface is [not a standard RS-232 type interface](https://www.kb6nu.com/ci-v/). The signals are TTL-level. It is a two-wire interface.

CI-V rig-to-computer interfaces can either be purchased, or built [using a simple  two transistor circuit](https://www.qsl.net/g3vgr/civ.html) or the [MAX-232](http://www.ka1mda.org/ham/homebrew/civ/index.htm) chip.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Icom IC-7610 Command Manual](http://www.icom.co.jp/world/support/download/manual/pdf/IC-7610_ENG_CI-V_0a.pdf), CI-V stands for "Computer Interface V".